# Customer community plus license user are not able to view reports in the community

Tags: community

Customer community plus license user are not able to view reports in the community.They have all the permission in their profile like run report etc.Please provide inputs.

Comment: do they have permissions on the report folders and objects for the relevant reports?

Comment: yes they have both object permission and the folder is shared to the community user.Not sure whether community user can see reports or not?

Comment: Community Plus users can see reports

Comment: not sure where I am missing out